# Default Location to System Drive in Setup and Deployment Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment

I have a setup and deployment project in Visual Studio 2010

The default location of Application Folder is set to C:\[Appname]

The problem is that if there is no drive C: in the machine the app is being installed, the installer will crash with an error "*'xxxxxxxx' is not a valid file name*" or something similar, because the installer verifies the location **before** the user has a chance to set the actual application installation folder. (so the default location is validated and since drive c: is missing it throws this error)

You can set the location to something like **[ProgramFilesFolder]**\[AppName] etc..

I would like to know what is the "macro" for **the system's windows drive**!
I would expect something like **[WindowsDrive]** or **[SystemDrive]** or something like that so that I could set the default location to **[SystemDrive]\[Appname]**, for instance!

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372057.aspx contains the info you are looking for(for .NET 3.5, other frameworks may differ).

Comment: Yes I found this link shortly after making the question :) The property I was looking for was "WindowsVolume".

I forgot to post it as my own answer, but hey... that earned you 25 points ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully the following explanation/screenshots will make it easier for future readers to set the default location:

#### How to set the Default location to the WindowsVolume?

- Use the WindowsVolume property.

#### Example:

[image: Screenshot on how to change the default location]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
[WindowsVolume][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```